# Returning java string instead of returning null

Tags: java, string, null, return

I wrote the method 'charCount()' to return String 'chc', but the netbean is forcing me to return null. Does the 'return null' also debarring me use the 'chc' outside this method,or it is well returned. Being new to java I am confused.

```
           //  static String chc ;

public static String charCount(String [] a){

             String chc ;

   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length(); j++) {
            char ch = a[i].charAt(j);
            int charcout = a[i].length();
            chc=  Character.toString(ch)+""+Integer.toString(charcout)+" ";
            //  String chc=  ch + "" + charcout + " ";
            return chc;  
            //System.out.print(chc);
        }
    } 
    return null; //NETBEAN IS FORCING ME TO WRITE THIS TO AVOID COMPILE TIME ERROR
}
```

I need help to rectify this code to avoid return null.

Comment: chc is not available outside the scope. You can declare chc before for loop.

Comment: If your goal is to return a String describing the frequency of every character in every String in the array, this method's logic will not accomplish that.  Once you fix the logic, the requirement to have `return null` at the end of the method probably will become irrelevant.  (Calling `return` in the middle of the loop means both loops will never execute more than once.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply wants you to return a "default" value in case your loop never gets executed (aka: if the array has no elements in it). You can either return `null` or a `String` (or a subclass of `String`, but there are none of that).

You cannot use `chc` there because `chc` is defined inside the scope of your inner loop. If you want more information about this you should look into "variable scope".

Comment: I am much aware of variable scope, I already I tried both places outside the loop (as edited now) but return null is still wanted by the netbean to compile.

Comment: What I have followed from you is that return null is ok here, in case the array is empty 'return null' is active. Being new to programming it is a great lesson from you. I have edited the code, kindly confirm that now it can return String "chc". If not then what change can is needed in the code to got the "chc" returned.

Comment: It will always want you to return *something*: either `null` or a type that is or inherits from `String`. Also note that you *have* to initialize local variables so what you have won't compile. You can no write `return null`, `return chc` or `return "chc"`.

Answer (score 0):

Java local variables *must* be initialized before use. The compiler can't be sure the loop will return a value, or even if it will iterate.

But!

Why are you even using a variable... eliminate it!

```
public static String charCount(String [] a){
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length(); j++) {
            char ch = a[i].charAt(j);
            int charcout = a[i].length();
            return Character.toString(ch)+""+Integer.toString(charcout)+" ";
        }
    } 
    return null;
}
```

This code is equivalent to yours, but doesn't use a variable.

As a side note, there doesn't seem much point in having a loop, as it returns on the first iteration of the inner loop. There is probably an error in your logic.